# How can I set Search Bar in list view using custom adapter?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-search, android-textwatcher

I want to add search bar in a list view using adapter class can anybody help me below is my code.
this is adapter class that I am using.
Cat_Headers_Home_Adapter.java

```
        public class Cat_Headers_Home_Adapter extends SectionAdapter {


        private Activity cntx;
        private List<Categories> categoriesList;
         private List<CatHeaders> categoriesHeadersList;

       public Cat_Headers_Home_Adapter(Activity cntx,List<Categories>categoriesList, List<CatHeaders> categoriesHeadersList) {

        this.cntx = cntx;
        this.categoriesList = categoriesList;
        this.categoriesHeadersList = categoriesHeadersList;

    }

    @Override
    public int numberOfSections() {
        return categoriesHeadersList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int numberOfRows(int section) {
        return categoriesList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getRowItem(int section, int row) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasSectionHeaderView(int section) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getRowView(int section, int row, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        Holder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) cntx
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_home_service_cat, null);
            holder = new Holder();
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (Holder) view.getTag();
        }

        Categories categories = categoriesList.get(section);
        holder.service_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.service_name);
        holder.count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.total);
        holder.service_icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.service_icon);
        holder.service_layout =    (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.service_layout);
        holder.service_name.setText(categories.catName);
        holder.count.setText(categories.count);
        holder.service_icon.setImageResource(categories.catImage);
        holder.service_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return view;
    }

    private class Holder {
        TextView service_name;
        TextView count;
        ImageView service_icon;
        LinearLayout service_layout;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSectionHeaderViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSectionHeaderItemViewType(int section) {
        return section % 2;
    }

    @Override
    public View getSectionHeaderView(int section, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = (TextView) cntx.getLayoutInflater().inflate(cntx.getResources().getLayout(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1), null);

        }


        ((TextView) convertView).setText(categoriesHeadersList.get(section).catName);
        ((TextView) convertView).setTextColor(cntx.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(cntx.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRowItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int section, int row, long id) {
        super.onRowItemClick(parent, view, section, row, id);
        Toast.makeText(cntx, "Section " + section + " Row " + row, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

this is a class i want to add a search bar on it
Home_fragment.java

```
    public class Home_Fragment extends Fragment {
    private HeaderListView list;
    private EditText searchBar;
    private int[] images;
    private String[] array;
    private String[] headers;
    private String[] fake_count;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listView;


    private List<Categories> categoriesList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<CatHeaders> categoriesListHeader = new ArrayList<>();

    public static Home_Fragment newInstance(int index) {
        Home_Fragment f = new Home_Fragment();

        // Supply index input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("position", index);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

    public int getShownIndex() {
        return getArguments().getInt("index", 0);
    }

    public Home_Fragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        listView = new ArrayList<>();
       images = Utils.getResourcesImages();
    //    images = getActivity().getResources().getIntArray(R.array.service_images_for_list_headers);
        array = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.services);
        headers = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.header_title);
        fake_count = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fake_count);

        for (int a = 0; a < images.length; a++) {

            int imageId = images[a];
            String count = fake_count[a];
            String name = array[a];

            Categories categoriesObj;

            if (a == 0 || a == 29 || a == 36 || a == 42 || a == 53) {
                categoriesObj = new Categories(name, imageId, count, true);
            } else {
                categoriesObj = new Categories(name, imageId, count, false);
            }

            categoriesList.add(categoriesObj);

        }

        for (int a = 0; a < headers.length; a++) {

            CatHeaders categoriesObj;

                categoriesObj = new CatHeaders(headers[a]);


            categoriesListHeader.add(categoriesObj);

        }


        Log.d("HOME Message Fragment", "Home Message Fragment");


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        list = (HeaderListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_view);






        searchBar = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.search_field);
        searchBar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (s.length() > 2) {
                    searchServiceFromList(s.toString());
                } else {
                    setOldView();
                }
            }

        });


        Arrays.sort(array);
        listView.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("service_name", array[i]);
            map.put("icon_position", Integer.toString(i));
            map.put("count", fake_count[i]);
            listView.add(map);
        }

        Cat_Headers_Home_Adapter adapter = new Cat_Headers_Home_Adapter(getActivity(),categoriesList,categoriesListHeader);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
//        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
//                HashMap<String, String> map = listView.get(position);
//                //  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), map.get("service_name").toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                //  objBook.show();
//                //  objBook.setService(map.get("service_name").toString());
//              /*  Post_New_Job_Fragment fragment = new Post_New_Job_Fragment();
//                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
//                bundle.putString("service_name", map.get("service_name").toString());
//                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
//                final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
//                ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment, "NewFragmentTag");
//                ft.addToBackStack(null);
//                ft.commit();*/
//                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Post_New_Job_Activity.class);
//                i.putExtra("service_name", map.get("service_name").toString());
//                i.putExtra("icon_position", map.get("icon_position").toString());
//                getActivity().startActivityForResult(i, 200);
//
//
//            }
//        });
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode) {
        super.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);

    }

    public void searchServiceFromList(String s) {
//        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
//        for (int i = 0; i < listView.size(); i++) {
//            HashMap<String, String> map = listView.get(i);
//            if ((map.get("service_name").toString().toLowerCase()).contains(s.toLowerCase())) {
//                tempList.add(map);
//            }
//        }
//
//        Home_Adapter adapter = new Home_Adapter(getActivity(), tempList, images);
//        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }`enter code here`

    public void setOldView() {
//        Home_Adapter adapter = new Home_Adapter(getActivity(), listView, images);
//        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}`enter code here`
```